# Specific mysql row to php code

Tags: php, mysql

With the code below I have to report to a table of rows from a database.

But in addition to the lines that I need, is displayed containing parts in php code (noName).

I try to keep only the echo tag

```
echo $row[0];
```

but i get the error

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in test.php on line 16
```

MYSQL

```
ID            |          Team
------------------------------
1                        test1
2                        test2
3                        test3
```

PHP

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("YourHost","user","password","dbName") or die('connection to DB failed');
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT team FROM s1");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_NUM)) {
?>

<table>
<tr>
    <td><p> team name <?php if(isset($row[0])){
                echo $row[0];
            }else{
                echo 'noName';
            } ?></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><p> team name <?php if(isset($row[1])){
                echo $row[1];
            }else{
                echo 'noName';
            } ?></p></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Output in php page:

```
test1

noName

test2

noName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting just 1 field that is `team` from the database.
So in your code PHP if you write `$row[0]` is the same if you write `$row['team']`.

`$row[1]` so is empty.

If you want print the name of all team you have to write this code:

```
...
echo "<table>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_NUM)) {
?>


<tr>
    <td><p> team name <?php echo $row[0]; ?></p></td>
</tr>
```

i would write your code like this:

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect("YourHost","user","password","dbName") or die('connection to DB failed');
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT team FROM s1");

if($query) {

    echo "<table>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><p> team name " . $row['team'] . "</p></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
}

?>
```

Comment: i need to receve sone specific team name. The complete code its here. http://pastebin.com/5UFFYuVS

Comment: first of all you should set the answer as correct because this resolve your issue. In some minutes i come back and solve you also this request no worries.

Comment: So what specific team name do you need? Tell me and we construct an easy query to extract just those

Comment: Starting from the database, there are 16 id with their team names on the side. Now open the file that I linked to above, I created a tournament bracket. The names of the team should be reported in the appropriate spaces (8. Team name, 9. Team name, 10. Teams name) etc ...

Comment: So what is the problem? i don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Look at your SQL query:

```
"SELECT team FROM s1"
```

You're only selecting one value from the table, the value called `team`.  So each row returned by this query will have only one value.  That value is in `$row[0]`.  Hence, there is no value in `$row[1]`.  In order to populate `$row[1]` with something, your `SELECT` will need at least a second value:

```
"SELECT team, someOtherValue FROM s1"
```

Of course, if your table *has* no other values, then there's nothing else to display...

It *looks like* you're trying to display the same conceptual value twice in each loop.  Why?  Generally each iteration of the loop would add a single row to the HTML table, not two rows.  Something like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_NUM)) {
?>

<table>
<tr>
    <td><p> team name <?php if(isset($row[0])){
                echo $row[0];
            }else{
                echo 'noName';
            } ?></p></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in test.php on line 4

Comment: @Metallic01: Sounds like maybe there's an error coming from the database.  Does `mysqli_error()` show anything?  In general you never want to assume that a database connection succeeded, always check before you try to use it.  Also, how did you change your query to produce that error?  If you copied/pasted my `someOtherValue` then of course that won't work.  And randomly copying/pasting code form the internet and running it without even reading it is generally a bad idea.